# how to return multiple record sets using json

Tags: php, json

I want to return multiple records instead of just 1 row.
JSON now returns only 1 row and I guess I need to add a while loop but not sure the right way to code it.

.js

```
function getq() {
    var q = $("#q").val();

    $.post(
        'getq.php',
        {q: q},
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, "json"
    );
}
```

getq.php

```
$q = $_POST['q'];
include("connect.php");
$sql = ("SELECT xxx FROM yyy WHERE zzz = $q");
if ($results=mysqli_query($db,$sql)) {
    $result = $results->fetch_assoc();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
I created the same case as yours on my pc, I used this javascript:

```
$.post('getq.php', {q: q}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

And this php (getq.php) file:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli( "localhost", "user", "passw", "db");

$q = $_POST['q'];

if ($results = $mysqli->query("SELECT xxx FROM yyy WHERE zzz = $q", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
    $result_set = mysqli_fetch_all($results,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($result_set);
    $results->close();
 }
?>
```

source: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_all.asp)

Comment: console.log(data) shows nothing. and I can't figure out how to display var_dump from the getq.php file since it's being called from javascript.

Comment: I edited the code I posted a bit, I tested this on my pc with a local dd. Using the code above it worked for me, if you still experience some trouble don't hesitate to comment.

Comment: Yes! That worked great. However, how do I now use the resulting data? console.log(data) shows: object, object, object... I can open those objects and see the associated data but console.log(data[0]) does not then show only object 1. Previously I would set various elements using something like: `document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = data['fname']+' '+data['lname'];` now how do I parse through the multi-record set?

Comment: Sorry, I was not correct. console.log(data[0]['fname']) does display the correct data within the first record. Now I can setup some structured loops. Thank you for assisting me.